# How can I get better photos of people on a lit stage using a Galaxy S5 phone?

Tags: smartphone, stage-lighting

Using a Galaxy S5 cell phone in low light indoors I want to get the best shots of people on a lit stage from maybe 25 ft away.  Faces tend to get blown out from white light.  Post processing doesn't help much. Suggestions?

Comment: That's a good place where the guys lugging around a 4 pound dslr can look smug. Double so if he rented a thousand dollar "fast" zoom lens for the occasion.  It makes sense that bigger camers outperform smaller and more basic ones; why would we carry them otherwise? Think about this: any improveent to the technology that gets used in a phone camera can also be applied, more so, to larger cameras.  You can have different specialized systems (e.g. lens for low light), and fewer conflicting requirements (e.g. thinness).

Comment: So, rather than worrying that your pre-chosen camera can handle that, look for the (smallest/cheapest/most-convenient) camera that can handle the situation with acceptable quality, and bring that. In general, low light means bigger pupil = lens bigger around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better camera would certainly be prefereable, but to answer the question directly: if you get blown out faces, reduce exposure by changing the EV setting to a negative value. The faces will get better, but the background will of course get darker, too.

(The problem here is that the camera is faced with a high contrast scene and tries to brighten up the dark background too much.)

Answer (score 0):

Phone camera's are extremely limited in their capabilities: they're mostly made for close-up photography and limited landscape photography. Because a phone has little real estate, the lens on a phone has to make concessions: this means limited to no optical zoom, a weak, fixed flash unit and a very relatively narrow minimum aperture.

In your situation, a phone camera is not suited because of the following:

- Long distance

A phone camera can usually only use digital zoom, this means that you're zooming in on the actual picture, which makes the end result worse in quality, so you're better off keeping it at the standard zoom.

- Bad lighting conditions

You have a lot of harsh light, and you need to compensate it, with something, like a flash. You can also darken the photo by changing the ISO, shutter speed, and f-stop. However, this will make other subjects on the photo darker as well.

- Bad flash capabilities

Most camera's use a bulky flash unit to light up photo's, for good reason. These flash units go much further than the tiny lamp that's fitted in the camera and you can also aim these units better: you bounce the light off a surface, instead of blowing out their faces by flashing head-on.

- No RAW capabilities

This depends wholly on your phone, but I don't think this applies to the S5. You can alter your photo's a great deal more if you shoot in RAW. You might not be able to directly view the photo on most devices, but it gives you much more control over editing the photo, because your camera records a lot more information. It gives you a lot more work, but the end result will be much better than editing JPG files.

My own suggestion would be to pick up a cheap compact camera and see how that fares, if you really want to try photography. They're pretty cheap, and you won't regret your purchase that much if it doesn't pan out that well. I'd especially recommend looking into canon compact camera's due to the [CHKD project](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK), which is a custom firmware that unlocks a myriad of options for your cheap compact.

Answer (score 0):

Other features that would be useful (after @shadowmanwkp 's answer) is being able to take longer exposures effectively.  This includes:

- image stabilization in the optics
- tripod (trumps the previous)
- being able to take fast burst shots, to get a "lucky shot" among them (and to use in fancy post processing)
- learning the *peak action* technique normally used for action shots.

Another thing to mention is that even an "old" (in computer years) dSLR with *quote* low *endquote* resolution will get you in a league well beyond a phone. Lenses are changable, and you can **rent** a high-end low-light lens for a couple days, to put on it.  In a nutshell, find the cheapeat Canon on ebay that is a dslr model that is supported by *Magic Lantern* software, with at least 6 megapixels. (I think anynsuch will have RAW files)